# How to use Landsat 8 or MODIS products to classify land area

Tags: area, software-recommendations, landsat, modis, clip

Anyone know of a good tutorial where I can learn how to use satellite vegetation imagery from Landsat or MODIS to classify which crops are grown where over time for a West african country. I don't need extremely good spatial resolution. I have reviewed the literature but most of it is impenetrable for a nonspecialist like me. FYI I don't have ground data. I want to take the inputs of the Landsat database and classify land area cover for different crops. I don't even know what software I would use to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is the Semi-Automatic Classification toolbox in QGis.

The plugin can be found [here](http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and a good basic tutorial can be found [here](http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorials.html#tutorial-1). On the same site as the tutorial, you can find other, more complex, tutorials on the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo Pro Advanced can also be used for multi-spectral analysis on Landsat data.

One benefit of using MapInfo Pro Advanced is the ability to merge multiple bands into one single grid (when using the MRR format).

Having all bands in one raster provides you the option to choose which band to "connect" to which RGB value, for example applying the Red, Green and Blue values, or to simply show a single band, for example the elevation.

Here are three examples showing this suing a grid greated from a set of Blom Kartta LIDAR files.

1. Here the grid shows the elevation
   [image]
2. here the same grid is set to show the intensity value from the LIDAR data
   [image]
3. And finally we switch to RGB mode and assign the RGB values from the grid to the Red, Green and Blue bands.
   [image]

In the case above we took 5 of the values from the LIDAR data when the grid file was created from the LIDAR points.

Here's an article from The MapInfo Pro Journal that gets you started: http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-dec-2015/Get-On-The-Grid-Working-With-Multispectral-Image-Files

Answer (score 0):

i wish the link help you to classify landsat 8 image using arcgis
[ARCGIS : Classifying Landsat image to make a land cover map](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHyJ_6j9-r0)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, can you add some explanation for the link you provided?